# Moving SSRS reports to physical location

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created a report using SSRS 2008 R2 and I need to copy the end report(.xlsx or .csv formats not .rdl file) to physical location.
anybody have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do it once, you can just export it and save it.

But if you want it done automatically on a regular basis, set up a subscription to place the file where you want (that the server can access) with Windows File Share. You must use the network path and not mapped drive letters. You would need some credentials to allow the report server to save the file.

[image]

[MSDN: SSRS Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762(v=sql.110).aspx)